# can we install virtual os(vm ware) on azure

Tags: azure, operating-system, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am new to azure i have a doubt that can we install more virtual operating systems in azure cloud operating system
`actually i have tried to implement a linux server in virtual machine later i got to know that  we can not connect to linux server using remote desktops now what i am thinking is to install a virtual box on server and install another os. is it works! if yes how to do this! i am faceing diffrent problems with diffrent iso files`

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to get a remote desktop experience on a Linux VM that is running on Azure?

Comment: yaa. i want to use azure linux server with windows remote desktop or any other software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install a virtualization service in a virtualized OS so no, you can't install VirtualBox in an Azure VM.

Yes you can RDP to a Linux VM in Azure.  This Microsoft blog page has all the info on how to do that:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/uktechnet/archive/2013/11/12/running-a-remote-desktop-on-a-windows-azure-linux-vm.aspx

Comment: its seems working but i strucked at the last step please see this image 
http://1drv.ms/1maNCsR